# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library sqlite3

Tags: apache, wamp

I've installed wamp 8.0.10-1 in my system and when I run the wamp, the below errors are generating in error.log. Basically, I want to install laravel 8, the system compatibility screen is throwing the below message:

```
SQLite3 Extension
PHP SQLite3 Extension is required.
```

error.log

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: D:/wampstack-8.0.10-1/php/ext\\sqlite3 (The specified module could not be found), D:/wampstack-8.0.10-1/php/ext\\php_sqlite3.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Oct 05 12:00:27.286105 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21832:tid 628] AH00455: Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/8.0.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 05 12:00:27.286105 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21832:tid 628] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Aug 25 2021 12:07:35
[Tue Oct 05 12:00:27.286105 2021] [core:notice] [pid 21832:tid 628] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\wampstack-8.0.10-1\\apache2\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wampstack-8.0.10-1/apache2 -f D:\\wampstack-8.0.10-1\\apache2\\conf\\httpd.conf'
[Tue Oct 05 12:00:27.286105 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21832:tid 628] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 20640
[Tue Oct 05 12:00:27.509826 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 20640:tid 584] AH01909: localhost:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 05 12:00:27.586616 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 20640:tid 584] AH01909: localhost:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: D:/wampstack-8.0.10-1/php/ext\\sqlite3 (The specified module could not be found), D:/wampstack-8.0.10-1/php/ext\\php_sqlite3.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Oct 05 12:00:27.614030 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 20640:tid 584] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

I've tried uncommenting `extension=sqlite3` in `php.ini`, but no luck. I feel this is path issue, but don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines in your **httpd.conf** file:

```
LoadModule php_module "C:/PHP/php8apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
LoadFile "C:/PHP/libssh2.dll"
LoadFile "C:/PHP/libsqlite3.dll"
```

And add full path in `extension_dir` setting in your **php.ini** file:

```
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"
```